# Hosting a WCF Service, error accessing it

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, service, hosting

I'm hosting a WCF service Application on somee.com using free hosting plan, now whenever I try to access the service I get this message:

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

does it mean that the server can't handle the svc extension?

//Edit

I tested the service on my machine using port forwarding and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, just added a proper handler in web.config

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to register WCF Service using ServiceModelReg.exe as described  at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx